# Conditionally Rendering Material UI Styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Currently building an application for a school project. I am looking to use an inline conditional render (i.e. condition ? expression1 : expression2) to determine what type of user is currently signed in (a doctor or a pharmacist), which is supposed to render the navbar a different color... a simplified version looks something like this...

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  docNav: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #F00000 30%, #DC281E 90%)',
  },

  pharmaNav: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #0575E6 30%, #021B79 90%)',
  }
});

const Navbar = ({ isPharmacist }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

    return (
      <AppBar className={classes.pharmaNav} position="static">
        <Toolbar variant="regular">
          <IconButton>
            <GitHubIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    ); //and then I also have a corresponding check statement with a similar return if the person signed in is a doctor...
```

So, to conditionally render the AppBar, depending on if isPharmacist is true or not, what may be a simple way to do this??? I tried `<AppBar className={isPharmacist ? classes.pharmaNav : classes.docNav }>`, but that didn't seem to work. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: your code looks fine with using `className`, both in your sample or your attempt of using `className={ condition ? phar : doc}`, so you should double check your `<AppBar />` component, make sure it accepts `className` as prop and spreading it into the parent div. Usually this is the root cause why your styling won't apply

Answer (score 22):

You can pass props into the first argument of `useStyles` like so:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  navbar: {
    background: props => props.isPharmacist
      ? 'linear-gradient(45deg, #0575E6 30%, #021B79 90%)'
      : 'linear-gradient(45deg, #F00000 30%, #DC281E 90%)',
  },
});

const Navbar = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return <div className={classes.navbar} />
}
```

Comment: According to this video, you can also pass in  a prop to the `navbar` method (e.g. `navbar: prop => ...`): https://youtu.be/k_AN49fA9g0?t=469

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming here, as this has been deprecated by Material-ui v4.
You can now use: [TSS](https://github.com/garronej/tss-react)
It works like a charm! :)